# Price of merging map data in Firestore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document with one field which is a `mapOf<String, Object>`. Multiple users can contribute to this map.

The code I use to add new data to the map:

```
val docRef = db.collection("data").document("document")
val updatedObject = FirebaseObject(data = mapOf("objectId" to FirebaseObjectItem(GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude), encodedCity)))
docRef.set(updatedObject, SetOptions.merge())
```

My question is what happens if I use above code to add the data to the map, which is already present? Does this count as document write?

Note: Next to map key, all the fields in `Object` are the same as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all calls to `set()`, `update()`, or `delete()` count as a write if they succeed.